# Is there a way of inserting a tilde (~) on a German keyboard without having to press space afterwards?

Tags: keyboard, catalina

I have a german keyboard layout (QWERTZ), and I often need to type a tilde (~) without any other symbols attached to it (e.g. ñ). Currently, the only way I know of to inset a tilde is <kbd>⌥ N</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, which is rather tedious. In comparison, on Windows I only need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>.

Is there a way to configure macOS to not require the additional spacebar press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to the Input Source called "German Standard", you can get ~ via <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Just type `option + n`, it should work

Comment: The problem is not getting the ~ but avoiding it turns into e.g. ã or similar.